# 401 Error Unauthorized when connecting to sharepoint 2013

Tags: 401

i have my sharepoint setup, and am rolling it out to the users.
on some PCs, i've experienced "401 Unauthorized" when the user is trying to connect.

ie
I have full access, and have granted access to a few users (read).
one user, it logged in straight away, didn't prompt for username or password.
then, for another user, he was prompted for his username and password. but it gave him the 401.
Also, i went logged on to another PC, and it gave me the 401.
Could set up of browsers be causing the issue?
Any suggestions ?
thanks

Comment: Does this happen in one specific browser?

Comment: Hi, on my own machine, i can log it to the site on both chrome and edge. on another pc, with the same credentials, i can't. that machine had chrome and ie 11.

Comment: have a look in the ULS logs to check which file the 401 error is related to.

Comment: This also my help **[SharePoint Workflow Suspended with Unauthorized 401](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-workflow-suspended-unauthorized/)**

Answer (score 3):

Might be late to the party, but I had that error and the solution was:
Go to IIS -> select the SharePoint Site -> double click "authentication" -> windows authentication -> Advanced Settings -> Check the box for "Enable Kernel-mode authentication"

Comment: Wow, this worked for me after so many days of trial and error. Thank you! Now I need to look why other site collections are working without this being enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Try this it will definitely solve your problem
https://www.helloitsliam.com/2015/03/06/sharepoint-2013-high-trust-provider-hosted-app-401-unauthorized-error/

Comment: While link may answer the question, but its still important to include some essential part of the link into the answer. Because once the link is broken, the answer become useless. Thanks